# How to store value in calc and continue counting?

Tags: java

How to modify the code so I can continuously count? So for example 2+3=5, and than -1 =4, until i press q to exit program ?? Please some simple solution for beginners. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter first number:");
            double num1 = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter second number");
            double num2 = sc.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Select operator (+,-,*,/) or enter q to exit:");
            char operator = sc.next().charAt(0);
            switch (operator) {
                case '+':
                    System.out.println("Result =" + Equasion.sum(num1, num2));
                    break;

                case '-':
                    System.out.println(Equasion.substract(num1, num2));
                    break;

                case'/':
                    if (num2 == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Divide by zero problem");
                    } else System.out.println(Equasion.divide(num1, num2));

                case '*':
                    System.out.println(Equasion.multiply(num1, num2));
                    break;

                case 'q':
                    System.exit(0);

            }
            System.out.println("Press any key to continue or q to quit");
        } while (!Objects.equals(ExitProg.exitProg(), 'q'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but you should move the first lines outside the while loop then overwrite the values of num1 and num2 every iteration (num2 becomes num1, then the user inputs another num2)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for responding CommunityBot. I'll try to elaborate if the OP asks without spoonfeeding answers as that goes against my code of conduct

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You mean the scanner lines outside of while? Could you please edit the code ?

Comment: I have to reiterate that I don't spoonfeed code for the sake of your understanding (and my time)

Comment: The general implementation would be to prompt the user to input the first and second number outside the loop, then operate these and if the user chooses to continue, then store the current value in the first variable and prompt for a second variable (at the end of the loop)